# Preferred method to `new` pointer to array

Tags: c++

Why is this an error:

```
typedef int H[4];

H * h = new H;        // error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[4]' in initialization
```

?

Furthermore, why is this *not* an error:

```
H * h = new H[1];
```

?

Why does the compiler consider that `new H` returns an `int *`, whereas `new H[1]` returns an `H *` as expected ?

To put it another way: **why is it that `T * t = new T;` is correct for a general type T, but is not correct when `T` is an array type ?**

What would be the canonical way to allocate a simple array type such as this via `new` ?

Note that this is a simplified example, so e.g. `new int[4]` is not an acceptable workaround - I need to use the actual type from the preceding `typedef`.

Note also that I'm aware that using `std::vector`, `std::array`, *et al* is generally preferable over C-style arrays, but I have a "real world" use case where I need to work with types such as the above.

Comment: In the 2nd case, `H[1]` is an array of arrays, so the new expression is a pointer to array.

Comment: `typedef int* H[4];`

Comment: @juanchopanza: thanks, yes, I get why the second example works, I'm just not clear why the first case doesn't compile.

Comment: @RahulTripathi: I don't see how that helps - that would make `H` an array 4 of pointers to `int`, no ?

Comment: Would putting H in a struct be a solution for you (`struct StrH { H h; };`)?

Comment: @PaulR I'm not completely sure I understand the issue, but `new H` is `new int[4]`, which is `int*`. But `H*` is pointer to `int[4]`, i.e. `int (*)[4]`.

Comment: @stefaanv: yes, I considered that, but I guess I'm first looking to understand why the obvious (to me at least) syntax doesn't work, and then secondly to see if there is a simple solution. So far the `new H[1]` workaround seems like a reasonable compromise, but having to do this feels "wrong".

Comment: Why not use std::array instead of dabbling with arcane typedefs and old-skool arrays?

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, I think you're probably right - I guess the mental block I'm having is why is `T * t = new T;` correct for a general type `T`, but is not correct when `T` is an array type ?

Comment: @ErikAlapää: see last paragraph of question.

Comment: @PaulR Yes, I see the point. Nobody said C++ was a pretty language :-) Speaking of which, you can probably play games with `decltype` and any operation that makes the array type decay to `int*`, but I'm not sure it would be "canonical".

Comment: @PaulR Or use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)?

Comment: @juanchopanza: thanks - I thought I might be missing something stupid/obvious. I'll stick with the `new H[1]` workaround for now unless anyone can come up with something more elegant.

Comment: @juanchopanza: thanks - I wasn't aware of `std::decay`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the real-world use case where `T *` works but `std::vector<T>` does not?

Comment: @Angew: it's a combination of requirements, but mainly interoperability with C and the need to do low-level optimisation (SIMD etc).

Comment: @PaulR: Was that paragraph there from the beginning, or did you add it?

Comment: @ErikAlapää: yes, that paragraph was there at the beginning - I knew *someone* would immediately chastise me for not using e.g. `std::array` (because that is what I would also do in the same cicrcumstances!). ;-)

Comment: Unless you need to pass the array around as `int **`, wouldn't `std::vector::data` be good enough for all such purposes?

Comment: @Angew: well it gets ugly because it's actually a 3D array (the question is a much simplified version of the actual use case). It *might* be possible to do it all the C++ way but when you start getting into the low-level optimisation stuff then the C++ abstractions can tend to get in the way.

Comment: Fair enough, multidimensional arrays can get tricky.

Comment: This is one of those cases where C++ makes quantum mechanics look easy, intuitive and straightforward...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C++ rule for the return type and value of `new T` is:

- If `T` is not an array type, the return type is `T *`, and the returned value is a pointer to the dynamically allocated object of type `T`.
- If `T` is an array of type `U`, the return type is `U *`, and the returned value is a pointer to the first element (whose type is `U`) of the dynamically allocated array of type `T`.

Therefore, since your `H` is an array of `int`, the return type of `new H` is `int *`, not `H *`.

By the same rule, `new H[1]` returns `H *`, but note that you have technicaly allocated a two-dimensional array of `int`s, sized 1 x 4.

The best way to get get around this in generic code is indeed to use `auto`:

```
auto h = new H;
```

Or, if you prefer to highlight the pointer fact:

```
auto *h = new H;
```

---

As for the rationale of this seeming inconsistency in the rules: pointers to arrays are quite "dangerous" in C++ since they behave rather unexpectedly (i.e. you have to be very careful with them not to produce unwanted effects). Let's look at this code:

```
typedef int H[4];
H *h = obtain_pointer_to_H_somehow();
h[2] = h[1] + 6;
```

At first (and maybe even second) glance, the code above seems to add 6 to the second `int` in the array and store it in the third `int`. But that's *not* what it does.

Just like for `int *p`, `p[1]` is an `int` (at the address `sizeof(int)` bytes offset from `p`), so for `H *h`, `h[1]` is a `H`, at the address `4 * sizeof(int)` bytes offset from `h`. So the code is interpreted as: take the address in `h`, add `4 * sizeof(int)` bytes to it, then add 6, and then store the resulting address at offset `8 * sizeof(int)` from `h`. Of course, that will fail, since `h[2]` decays to an rvalue.

OK then, you fix it like this:

```
*h[2] = *h[1] + 6;
```

Even worse now. `[]` binds tighter than `*`, so this will reach into the 5th `int` object after `h` (note there are only 4 of them there!), add 6, and write that into the 9th `int` after `h`. Writing into random memory FTW.

To actually do what the code was probably intended to, it would have to be spelled like this:

```
(*h)[2] = (*h)[1] + 6;
```

In light of the above, and since what you usually do with a dynamically allocated array is access its elements, it makes more sense for `new T[]` to return `T *`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the rule - it seems bizarre but I expect there's a good reason for it ("something something decay to pointer...").

Comment: @PaulR it's "bizarre" that `int *p = new int[5];` is legal?

Comment: @M.M. good point - I suppose you can't have it both ways - it only seems bizarre to me right now because of the inconsistency in what `new T` returns (as described in the answer above).

Comment: @M.M: it may seems bizarre that `T* p = new T;` doesn't work for some type (as array, reference)).

Comment: @PaulR I added a discussion of what I believe the good reason to be.

Comment: @Jarod42 obviously you can't have both `int *p = new int[5];`, and `int (*p)[5] = new int[5];` ...  requiring the second would seem more bizarre to me

Comment: @Angew: thanks - nice answer - I'm sure it will help others in the future who might be scratching their heads over this same issue.

Comment: Has anybody tried to see what type of "h" for  auto *h = new H;? See https://www.godbolt.org/z/non5bvTY6                                                                                           typedef int H[4];
auto *h = new H;
static_assert(is_same_v<H*, int(*)[4]>);
static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(h), int*>);

Comment: @NickHuang Yes, that's consistent with the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Main Question

> [What is the] Preferred method to `new` pointer to array

Constraint:

> Note also that I'm aware that using std::vector, std::array, et al is generally preferable over C-style arrays, but I have a "real world" use case where I need to work with types such as the above.

Answer:

for the non-array case:

```
#include <memory>

auto h = std::make_unique<H>();

// h is now a std::unique_ptr<H> which behaves to all intents and purposes
// like an H* but will safely release resources when it goes out of
// scope
// it is pointing to a default-constructed H

// access the underlying object like this:
h.get(); // yields H*
*h;      // yields H&
```

For the array case:

```
#include <memory>

auto h = std::make_unique<H[]>(4);

// h is now a std::unique_ptr<H[]> which behaves to all intents and purposes
// like an H* but will safely destruct and deallocate the array 
// when it goes out of scope
// it is pointing to an array of 4 default-constructed Hs

// access the underlying object like this:
h[1];     // yields H& - a reference to the 2nd H
h.get();  //yields H* - as if &h[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

In the C++ standard `new` and `new[]` are specifically separated because they can be be different allocators for performance and efficiency reasons; allocating an array vs. a single object has different usage patterns that allocator implementations optimise for.

The syntax is probably different because the compile-time type introspection techniques available when it was standardised wasn't nearly as reliable as it is today.

To make sensible code, the preferred way IMO would be:

```
struct H { int values[4]; }

H * h = new H;
```

That way, your `H` type logically "contains" your array of four `int` values - but the in-memory structure should still be compatible (`assert(sizeof(H) == 4 * sizeof(int))`); and you get to use object-style allocation of your fixed-size arrays.  More... C++-ey.

Comment: @Jarod42 OP acknowledges that in the question - is it necessarily pointer-compatible, though?

Answer (score 0):

You can see why if you basically do the typedef substitution manually:

```
H * h = new H;
```

Reduces to:

```
int[4]* h = new int[4];
```

while

```
H * h = new H[1];
```

reduces to:

```
(int*)[4] h = new int[1][4];
```

Because of the array to pointer decay rules, this is legal.

If you want an actual workaround, and you know the type of H, you can do something like:

```
typedef int* J;
typedef int H[4];

J j = new H; // This will work
```

Comment: `int[4]* h` is not legal syntax, it should be `int (*h)[4]`; and it is `new int[1][4]`

Comment: @Yuushi: the actual array type is much more complex than the example in the question (it's a 3D array) - it looks like using `auto` might be a good solution though.

Comment: You give a useless answer. What he asks is a way to get "int(*)[4]" by "new" method, not just a "int*".